# How to receive date values using Microsoft Bot Framework (chatbot programming)

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

[screen capture of code + directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZsVV.png)

I'm working on creating a beauty salon reservation chatbot with Microsoft Bot Framework on Visual Studio. The language used is C#; please note that I am in the process of learning and therefore am new to all of this. This is also my first time posting on stackoverflow so I apologise if my question is slightly unhelpful or unclear :(

What I'm trying to do here is receive a date input value, ask for a time input value, then receive a name input value. When I run this code the bot doesn't respond after date input. I know this code is pathetic and dysfunctional in the first place but my brain's overflowing - I'm stuck and out of ideas. Any potential fixes would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

```
private async Task ReservationDateMessageAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> beforeActivity)
{
    await context.PostAsync($"예약하실 날짜를 입력해주세요~ \n\n 예)12월 31일");
    context.Wait(ResolvationTime);
}

private async Task ResolvationTime(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    var activity = await result as Activity;
    memberReservation.Date = activity.Text; // Save reservation date value

    //2.1 시간 선택 (Time selection)
    if (activity.Text.Equals("") == false || !activity.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        List<CardAction> salon_Button = new List<CardAction>();
        salon_Button.Add(new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "10시 ~ 13시",
            Value = "10시 ~ 13시",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack
        });
        salon_Button.Add(new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "14시 ~ 17시",
            Value = "14시 ~ 17시",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack
        });
        salon_Button.Add(new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "17시 ~ 20시",
            Value = "17시 ~ 20시",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack
        });
        salon_Button.Add(new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "이전으로", // Previous stage
            Value = "이전으로",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack
        });

        HeroCard salon_Card = new HeroCard()
        {
            Title = activity.Text,
            Subtitle = "원하시는 시간을 선택해주세요 ^^", // Please select the desired time
            Buttons = salon_Button
        };

        var message = context.MakeMessage();
        message.Attachments.Add(salon_Card.ToAttachment());
        context.Wait(this.OnReservationTimeSelected);
    }
    else
    {

        //다시 이전(날짜부터 다시 묻기) 질문하기 (Return to previous question)

        await this.ReservationDateMessageAsync(context, null);

    }

}

/// <summary>
/// 예약시간 선택완료 (Reservation time selection done)
/// </summary>

/// <param name="context"></param>
/// <param name="result"></param>
/// <returns></returns>

private async Task OnReservationTimeSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;
    memberReservation.Time = message.Text;

    if (message.Text == "10시 ~ 13시" || message.Text == "1")
    {
    // Display reservation time and ask for name input
        await context.PostAsync($" { memberReservation.Date} { memberReservation.Time}에 예약하셨습니다.\n\n 성함을 입력해주세요.\n\n "); 
        context.Wait(this.GetUserNameAsync);
    }
    else if (message.Text == "14시 ~ 17시" || message.Text == "2")
    {
        await context.PostAsync($" { memberReservation.Date}에 { memberReservation.Time}에 예약하셨습니다.\n\n 성함을 입력해주세요.\n\n ");
        context.Wait(this.GetUserNameAsync);
    }

    else if (message.Text == "17시 ~ 20시" || message.Text == "3")
    {
        await context.PostAsync($" { memberReservation.Date}에 { memberReservation.Time}에 예약하셨습니다.\n\n 성함을 입력해주세요.\n\n  ");
        context.Wait(this.GetUserNameAsync);
    }
    else if (message.Text == "이전으로")
    {
        await this.ResolvationTime(context, result);
    }
    else
    { // Error message
        await this.StartOverAsync(context, "죄송합니다. 요청사항을 이해하지 못했습니다.^^; ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling dates in Bot Framework usually involves using `DateTime` recognizers and analyzing the multiple possible `DateTime` resolutions. And it isn't extremely complicated but it isn't trivial either.

There are a lot of concepts to explain here but I'll try to synthesize.

When you get a `DateTimeResolution` you can get four type of results:

- A single DateTime
- Several possible DateTimes
- A single DateTime range
- Several DateTime ranges

So you have to handle those possibilities and decide if you can get something useful from there.

For example if the user says "on Monday" you'll get the dates for last Monday and for next Monday so, depending on your context, you decide which is the valid one or request further refinement.

Considering you're getting started, I'd suggest that you take a look at this Bot Framework sample project: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/44.prompt-users-for-input

Anyway, you might also want to take a look at [Bot Framework Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/composer/introduction), just in case you want to get to a working bot faster, with a low-code solution.